# setup GitLab SSH key for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ssh, gitlab

Having issues creating an ssh credential in Jenkins that allows access to GitLab.  I have 2 AWS instances, one with GitLab and one with Jenkins.  I would like to setup a multibranch pipeline in Jenkins to run a GitLab repo.  I am able to create the pipeline and can access GitLab if I use a username/password credential (using "root"/initial password) but would like to use the more secure route of using a username/SSH credential.  I have generated the SSH (of the ed25519 variety) in the GitLab instance (while in root). Then, in  GitLab, supplied the public key to the root user.  Then, in Jenkins, provided the private SSH key and set username as "root" in a username/SSH credential.  When I try to run the pipeline using the username/SSH credential I get an error indicating that it is not authorized.  Should I be using a different username?  Should I be generating the SSH key in a different location?

Comment: In your case, it's considered a bad practice to use root. Maybe try to call it Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it was something small I was missing.  I was configuring the pipeline job for the http url of the repo rather than the SSH url.  Once I changed that, it worked right away.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).